# How to validate data using sql statement to ensure user does not breach the system

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am using JDBC and mySQL to do an application for a family. After logging in into the system, the user can register for a family account. By SQL statement, I want to ensure that the input they keyed in is not repeated and they can only register when the database have a NRIC of them individually. I am working with JDBC and implementing the SQL statement in Java also. **For now my problem is the system does not validate the input the user keys in and let's the information to be passed to database easily.** Would appreciate some help!

*NRIC = Identity Card No

Snapshots of Database:

User Database

[image: User Database]

Family Account Database

[image: Family Account Database]

Code

```
public boolean regFamily(FamilyAccount myFam, Customer myCust) throws Exception {
    int fid = 0;
    try {

        String selectStatement2 = "SELECT * from familyok.user where nric = ?  and  familyid is NOT NULL ";
        PreparedStatement pStmt2 = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement2);
        pStmt2.setString(1, myCust.getNric());
        ResultSet rs2 = pStmt2.executeQuery();
        if (rs2.next()) {

            String insertStatement = "Insert into familyok.familyaccount (familyname, fnric1, fnric2, fnric3)";
            insertStatement = insertStatement + "values (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(insertStatement);
            prepStmt.setString(1, myFam.getFamilyname());
            prepStmt.setString(2, myFam.getFnric1());
            prepStmt.setString(3, myFam.getFnric2());
            prepStmt.setString(4, myFam.getFnric3());
            int status = prepStmt.executeUpdate();
            if (status != 0) {

                String selectStatement = "SELECT fid FROM familyok.familyaccount WHERE fnric1=?";
                PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
                pStmt.setString(1, myFam.getFnric1());
                ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("fid") + "\t");
                    fid = rs.getInt("fid");

                    String updateStatement = "update familyok.user set familyid=?, familyname1=? where nric in (?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(1, fid);
                    preparedStmt.setString(2, myFam.getFamilyname());
                    preparedStmt.setString(3, myFam.getFnric1());
                    preparedStmt.setString(4, myFam.getFnric2());
                    preparedStmt.setString(5, myFam.getFnric3());

                    int status2 = preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("update=" + preparedStmt.toString());

                    if (status2 != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Family Account Created");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Can't Register");
            return false;

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You said you were using Java EE. But none of this is Java EE. This is JDBC which is part of Java SE. Java EE has JPA.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Much appreciated..

Comment: *"the system does not validate the input the user keys in"* - Do you mean that `rs2.next()` is returning `false`?